# How to fix water leakage from drain hose of a washing machine?

Tags: leak, drain, washing-machine

We have this washing machine connection, which was setup by the installer some years back that has started leaking now. Probably it was not setup correctly, but we want to fix this to avoid the leakage. We also wanted to avoid paying a plumber for the same and do it ourselves.

We tried putting additional tape, but that did not work. How to best go about fixing this leakage correctly?

[image]

Comment: `ProTip™`: Electrical tape is _never_ the answer for plumbing problems. It's not even particularly good for simply labeling pipes (unless you just want colored markings on the pipes).

Comment: What's the other side of that wood panelling? Hopefully a trap.

Answer (score 4):

Normally the drain hose hooks over the top of an upward-pointing pipe which goes down a few feet, goes through a trap, and then down into the drains. Gravity prevents backflow/leakage.

Someone tried to do something "creative" in your case by cutting off the hook and skipping at least the first section of pipe.

I'm not sure the pump is strong enough to sent the water high enough to let you add all the missing piping outside the wall. But it should be enough to go a bit higher. You could experiment with a bucket to test that. Or check the owner's manual.

Assuming that is possible, Id strip off the tape, use PVC cement to add a p-trap and a vertical section of the proper size, and replace the butchered drain hose with an intact one that has the hook.

Comment: Good catch, corrected.